# Django: Grouping and ordering across foreign keys with conditions

Tags: python, sql, django

I have some Django models that record people's listening habits (a bit like Last.fm), like so:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Song(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
    title = models.CharField()

class SongPlay(models.Model):
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    time = models.DateTimeField()

class User(models.Model):
    # doesn't really matter!
```

I'd like to have a user page where I can show the top songs that they've listened to in the past month. What's the best way to do this?

The best I've come up with so far is:

```
SongPlay.past_month
    .filter(user=user)
    .values('song__title', 'song__id', 'song__artist__name')
    .annotate(plays=Count('song'))
    .order_by('-plays')[:20]
```

Above, `past_month` is a manager that just filters plays from the last month. Assume that we've already got the correct `user` object to filter by as well.

I guess my two questions are:

- **How can I get access to the original object as well as the `plays` annotation?**
  This just gives me certain values, based on what I pass to `values`. I'd much rather have access to the original object – the model has methods I'd like to call.
- **How can I group from `SongPlay` to `Artist`?**
  I'd like to show a chart of artists, as well as a chart of songs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the same field in both `values` and `annotate`.

You have the primary key of the `Song` object (you could just use `song` instead of `song__id`), so use

```
Song.objects.get(id=...)
```

For your second question, do a separate query with `song__artist` as the field in `values` and `annotate`:

```
from django.db.models import Count

SongPlay.past_month
    .filter(user=user)
    .values('song__artist')
    .annotate(plays=Count('song__artist'))
    .order_by('-plays')[:20]
```

Comment: I did think about option 1 already, but I wondered if there was a more efficient way to do it than just using `Song.objects.get` for each row of the result.

Comment: Can you give an example? I can't get `values('song')` and `select_related(depth=1)` to give me anything other than a dictionary of song ID and number of plays.

Comment: @Sam Wow, I'm sorry, I blanked on that. You can only get the actual db fields with values, not objects. When you group, you're not accessing the related table, just the foreign key field.

Comment: @Sam Keep in mind `get` on a primary key is fast, though still unfortunate because it's a separate query.

Comment: @Sam Also read about the effects of `order_by` on grouping. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by

Answer (score 0):

agf has already showed you how to group by song_artist.   What I would do to get the actual Song object is store it in memcached, or if the method you are calling is rather simplistic make it a static method or a class method.  You might could also initialize a Song object with the data from the query and not actually save it to get access to this method.  Might help to know the details of the methods you want to call from the Song object.